# Помогите с методом разности множеств

Tags: java, множества

Я начал писать метод разности множеств и застрял на месте, помогите разобратся

> Метод должен принимать на вход два объекта класса Set и возвращать соответствующее множество в виде одномерного массива.
> Все классы и методы должны уметь работать со множествами разного типа (целые числа, дробные числа, символы, логические значения).
> Запрещается в качестве контейнера для элементов множеств использовать какие-либо классы коллекций.

```
public class Set<T> {

    private T[] set;
    
    public void setSet(T[] set) {
        this.set = (T[]) Arrays.stream(set).distinct().toArray();
    }
    
    public T[] getSet() {
        return set;
    }
    
    public Set(T[] array) {
        setSet(array);
    }

public boolean contains(T elem, Object[] array) {
        for (T element : (T[]) array) {
            if (elem.equals(element)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
public T[] diferenceSets (Set s1, Set s2) {
        T[] result = (T[])new Object[s1.getSet().length];
        int iter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.getSet().length; i++) {
            if(!contains((T) s1.getSet()[i], s2.getSet())){
                result[iter] = (T) s1.getSet()[i];
                iter++;
            }
        }
        return result;
```

Результат

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Set s1 = new Set(new Object[] {5, 11, "String", 15.98, 24.85, true});
        
        Set s2 = new Set(new Object[] {7, 11, "Str", 23.2, 24.85, false});
        
        Operation operation = new Operation();
        
        Object[] x = operation.diferenceSets(s1, s2);

        
        x = operation.diferenceSets(s1, s2);
        for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
        }
}
```

В консоли

```
5 String 15.98 true null null
```

Почему выводит null null(2 неподходящих елемента), может проблема в методе?

Comment: .. и в чем именно состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: не знаю что возвращать

Comment: *".. и возвращать соответствующее множество в виде одномерного массива"*

Comment: я написал return result, но есть небольшая проблемка

Comment: Добавляйте уточнения в тело вопроса - кнопка "править".

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно у вас находится в классе `Operation` (оба метода `contains` `differenceSets` или только один), и нужен ли он вам вообще, так как вполне достаточно было бы реализовать эти функции внутри `Set`.  Также, если вы уже используете собственную реализацию "множества" на основе массива, то операции следует выполнять над своими `Set`'ами, а не над массивами объектов, что относится и к методу `differenceSets`.  Ну и неплохо было бы использовать какое-то своё название типа `ArraySet`, не совпадающее со стандартным интерфейсом `Set`

Comment: в классе operation оба метода contains и differenceSets

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант реализации без отдельного класса для операций `Operation`:

```java
public class ArraySet<T> {

    private T[] set;
    
    public void setSet(T[] set) {
        this.set = (T[]) Arrays.stream(set).distinct().toArray();
    }
    
    public T[] getSet() {
        return set;
    }
    
    public ArraySet(T[] array) {
        setSet(array);
    }
    
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "ArraySet: " + Arrays.toString(this.set);
    }
    
    public boolean contains(T elem) {
        return Arrays.stream(this.set).anyMatch(it -> Objects.equals(it, elem));
    }
    
    public ArraySet<T> difference(ArraySet<T> that) {
        return new ArraySet<>(
            (T[]) Arrays.stream(this.set)
                .filter(it -> !that.contains(it))
                .toArray()
        );
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
ArraySet<Object> s1 = new ArraySet<>(new Object[] {5, 11, "String", 15.98, 24.85, true});
        
ArraySet<Object> s2 = new ArraySet<>(new Object[] {7, 11, "Str", 23.2, 24.85, false});
        
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println("s1 - s2 = " + s1.difference(s2));
System.out.println("s2 - s1 = " + s2.difference(s1));
```

Вывод:

```
ArraySet: [5, 11, String, 15.98, 24.85, true]
ArraySet: [7, 11, Str, 23.2, 24.85, false]
s1 - s2 = ArraySet: [5, String, 15.98, true]
s2 - s1 = ArraySet: [7, Str, 23.2, false]
```

---

Реализация операций в отдельном классе:

```java
public class Operation {
    public static <T> boolean contains(T elem, T[] arr) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(it -> Objects.equals(it, elem));
    }
    
    public static<T> T[] difference(ArraySet<T> first, ArraySet<T> second) {
        return (T[]) Arrays.stream(first.getSet())
                .filter(it -> !contains(it, second.getSet()))
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, но мне нужно именно клас Operation(

Comment: всегда можно вынести функционал в отдельный класс, смотрите апдейт